# Is it necessary to declare the attributes of a superclass in the extended class?

Tags: java

I'm just starting in programming and I have this doubt. For example, if I have to make a constructor in the class, do I have to declare the atributes of the superclass so I can make it?

Comment: What happens when you try doing so? And what happens when you try omitting them?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of software :) Just like Silvio suggests, simply just trying things and seeing what happens is a very effective way to learn. If you mean something like a class called `Dog` which inherits `Animal`, "does the `Dog` class need to set `Animal.LegCount` in the constructor of `Dog`"  - No, it doesn't, but it probably should - it depends on what you need it to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.